# WP media library doesn't load after adding child .css

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The wordpress media library won't load anything after I put this in my functions.php of my child theme:

```
function custom_manage_styles_and_scripts() {
  wp_register_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_manage_styles_and_scripts', 99 );

?>
```

The child .css file works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will happen if you only enqueue the style? Like this:

```
function custom_manage_styles_and_scripts() { 
 wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_manage_styles_and_scripts', 99 );
```